# SQL: select all rows with same id in field 1 where field 2 meets criteria

Tags: sql

I've got a table with two fields.

If code = A then go to the first column(Batch) and look at the value.
The value is 1.
Then select all rows where batch = 1

If for a specific batch the code is not A then these records are not selected

The result of this query would be only the rows containing Batch = 1 because one of the lines where batch =1 has got code = A

```
Batch   code
_____________
1        A
1        B
1        C
1        D
2        B
2        B
2        C
2        D
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Batch, Code
FROM table t1
WHERE Batch = (SELECT Batch FROM table t2 WHERE code='A')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this...

```
 SELECT batch, code
    FROM yourtable
    WHERE batch IN (SELECT batch FROM yourtable WHERE code='A')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IN` for this.  First, create a query that will find the value for `Batch` where `Code = 'A'`:

```
SELECT Batch
FROM   YourTable
WHERE  Code = 'A'
```

Then use this logic as a subquery with `IN`:

```
SELECT Batch, Code
FROM   YourTable
WHERE  Batch IN (
     SELECT Batch
     FROM   YourTable
     WHERE  Code = 'A'
)
```

`IN` is preferred over `=` here, as it covers for cases where there are multiple batch values with code 'A'.